DigiCert - Azure DevOps YAML task SSMClientToolsSetup@1 Fails with "The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed" Error
Azure pipeline fails on the SSMClientToolsSetup@1 task:
Starting: SSMClientToolsSetup
==============================================================================
Task         : Installer for DigiCert One Software Trust Manager Client tools
Description  : Installs Client Tools to use with DigiCert One Software Trust Manager
Version      : 1.7.0
Author       : DigiCert
Help         : 
==============================================================================
using path  C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp
Tool to be downloaded and used {} and url is {} smtools-windows-x64.msi signingmanager/api-ui/v1/releases/noauth/smtools-windows-x64.msi/download
file after write  96681984
C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /i C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\smtools-windows-x64.msi /quiet INSTALLDIR=C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\smtools-windows-x64
The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed. This can occur if the Windows Installer is not correctly installed. Contact your support personnel for assistance.


error when executing setup task of STM Error: The process
'C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe' failed with exit code 1601
at ExecState._setResult (C:\azagent\A1_work_tasks\SSMClientToolsSetup_63dc66e6-daa5-4c1c-97f2-4312143a6d6c\1.7.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:942:25)
at ExecState.CheckComplete (C:\azagent\A1_work_tasks\SSMClientToolsSetup_63dc66e6-daa5-4c1c-97f2-4312143a6d6c\1.7.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:925:18)
at ChildProcess. (C:\azagent\A1_work_tasks\SSMClientToolsSetup_63dc66e6-daa5-4c1c-97f2-4312143a6d6c\1.7.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-task-lib\toolrunner.js:838:19)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)

##[error]The process 'C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe' failed with exit code 1601
Finishing: SSMClientToolsSetup

Things I have tried already but none of them helped:

Made retryCountOnTaskFailure: 10 on the task
Manually installed smtools-windows-x64 file
Verified Windows Installer service is up and running but did notice it stops after some time.
Restarted server
Manually ran msiexec.exe command on CmdLine but that works



You seem has configured your self-hosted Windows agent to use the default Windows built-in account 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' on the agent service to login the machine. The account 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' might not have the permissions to download and install the .msi package on the machine.
I notice that you can download and install the .msi package when you manually login the machine with the admin account.
To resolve the issue in the pipeline, you can also try to configure the agent service to login the machine with the admin account.

Manually login the machine with the admin account.

Search for Services and open it. Find the running agent service.

Then you can change the logon account as admin account.





Thanks @Bright Ran-MSFT. This really helped. I didn't use the .\Administrator account but used SYSTEM account and that worked.

The task is from the Azure DevOps extension Code signing with Software Trust Manager. I tried the task on the Microsoft hosted agent, and it works without error.

Also, I tried to download the smtools-windows-x64.msi from  https://one.digicert.com/signingmanager/api-ui/v1/releases/noauth/smtools-windows-x64.msi/download and install it on my VM manually, it works without error.
As you said you manually installed smtools-windows-x64 file and verified Windows Installer service is up and running, but you did notice it stops after some time.  It seems there is something wrong with the environment of your self-hosted agent.
You can try to use the Microsoft hosted agent and see if it works in your side. Or use another VM as self-hosted agent to try again.

So is the Windows Installer service supposed to be running all the time?

When I install the smtools-windows-x64.msi manually by clicking the file, it will start the installer program and it can install without problem. The screenshot is here. Is this installer program stopped when you install it?

No, it doesn't stop. I am able to manually install smtools-windows-x64.msi without issues. Only when the msiexec.exe runs from Azure Pipelines task, it fails.

To test I added another task just to see if msiexec.exe was running fine but I still get the same error. How can I fix this Windows Installer error? =>- task: CmdLine@2
inputs:     script: 'C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /i C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\smtools-windows-x64.msi INSTALLDIR=C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\smtools-windows-x64'

Could you please run the CmdLine script manually and see if the same error will happen?  This way we can know if the issue is related to Azure Pipeline or the msiexec.exe itself on your agent. I tested the command in my local, it works.

I ran this command C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /i C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\smtools-windows-x64.msi INSTALLDIR=C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\smtools-windows-x64 manually on CmdLine and it works fine. Only when msiexec.exe is invoked via Azure Pipeline is when the error is occurring.

I have updated my question to include the screenshot when I run the above

Hi , could you please also try to run this command C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /i C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\smtools-windows-x64.msi /quiet INSTALLDIR=C:\azagent\A1\_work\_temp\smtools-windows-x64 manually on CmdLine which is the same as the one in the pipeline? It added additional  /quiet  to the command.
